# Squares on Gnome 3 Title Bar

Tags: gnome3

Updated the Kali Linux and as a result, updated the Gnome to version 3.20.1, but is now appearing in the title bar (and other places in some Gnome applications) squares instead of letters. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an [answer over at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749985/square-characters-on-gnome-titlebar-and-some-system-settings). It looks like some fonts are missing and need to be re-installed. Here's the steps from that answer:

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
sudo fc-cache -fv
```

Reboot your machine and it should have the title bars fixed.